# c++ invoke base classes' virtual operator== with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, multiple-inheritance

Given the following excerpts:

```
class Interface {
public:
    virtual bool operator==(const Interface &other) const = 0;
    virtual void print(ostream& sout) const = 0;
};

class A : virtual public Interface {
public:
    virtual bool operator==(const Interface &other)const;
    virtual void print(ostream& sout)const;

protected:
    short m_foo;
};

class B : virtual public Interface {
public:
    virtual bool operator==(const Interface &other)const;
    virtual void print(ostream& sout) const;

protected:
    short m_bar;
};

class C: public A, public B {
public:
    virtual bool operator==(const Interface &other) const;
    virtual void print(ostream& sout) const;
};
```

In C.cpp I'm trying to implement operator==:

```
bool C::operator==(const Interface &other) const {
    try {
        // This works, but it's duplicating code from A.cpp and B.cpp
        const C& otherC = dynamic_cast<const C&>(other);
        return (m_foo == otherC.m_foo && m_bar == otherC.m_bar);

        // This doesn't work -- it calls C::operator== instead of
        // A::operator== and B::operator== (infinite recursion).
        /*
        return (dynamic_cast<const A&>(*this) ==
                dynamic_cast<const A&>(other) &&
                dynamic_cast<const B&>(*this) ==
                dynamic_cast<const B&>(other));
                */
    } catch (bad_cast e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can get it to work for the output method, but I don't know how to do
something equivalent when overriding operators:

```
void C::print(ostream& sout) const {
    A::print(sout);
    sout << " ";
    B::print(sout);
}
```

Is there a way to call the base classes' virtual operators instead of doing
something like adding a virtual equals() method and just having operator== call
that?

(Note: this code is based off of a small part of a homework assignment in case
that's relevant.)

Comment: BTW, catching `bad_cast` is poor practice.  Just use `dynamic_cast<const C*>(&other)` and test for NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return A::operator==(other) && B::operator==(other);
```

The two base classes should handle any type error in `other`, so you don't need to do anything about that here.

EDIT: rewrote code to use explicit call.

Comment: @user1258629 - that's the general pattern for calling the base class version of an overridden function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly name the operator you want to use.

Replace:

```
    return (dynamic_cast<const A&>(*this) ==
            dynamic_cast<const A&>(other) &&
            dynamic_cast<const B&>(*this) ==
            dynamic_cast<const B&>(other));
```

With **Edit: corrected**

```
    return (A::operator==( other ) &&
            B::operator==( other ));
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error about "no matching function" though. It says the candidate expects 1 argument instead of 2. I'll post some more info in a minute after I mess around a bit.